# Jmeter JSR223 Pre processor and sampler

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter

I have a jsr223 preprocessor in the concurrency thread group which creates data to send it to Kafka producer. and I have a JSR sampler that uses Kafka client 2.7.0 to send messages to Kafka procedure.
The message sent to Kafka should be different each time for e.g. it has device information which should be different and events with time (which is the current time).  These are been generated without any issues as I tested it with few
(50) threads. The problem I am having is when I want to send more messages like 6000 messages per second. How to resolve this issue
below is my setup
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're showing us a screenshot of the Concurrency Thread Group configured to start 6000 threads (virtual users) and hold them for 20 seconds.

It will result in 6000 messages per second only if your JSR223 PreProcessor and Sampler cumulative response time is exactly 1 second. If it will be less - you will generate more messages per second and vice versa.

For example:

- if PreProcessor and Sampler execution time is 500ms - you will end with 12000 messages per second
- if PreProcessor and Sampler execution time is 2000ms - you will send 3000 messages per second

If you're sending less messages than you need - consider following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), at least disable all the Listeners and run your test in non-GUI mode. Still not enough? Increase the concurrency. Increased concurrency, lacking resources and still not enough - go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

If you're sending more messages than 6000 per second you can limit JMeter sampler execution rate to the desired throughput using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117628/spring-boot-rest-api-server-connection-timed-out-sometime/67123550#67123550)

You can see your current throughput using i.e. [Transactions per Second listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)

Comment: I am running in non-GUI mode and I did set up as per your suggestion. the above screenshot is an example of how it's been set up. I will disable the listeners and try playing with concurrency thread