# Spring Boot REST API server Connection timed out sometime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jmeter

I'm testing my Spring Boot REST API server with Apache JMeter.

Most of 'Connect Time' is in 10ms, but connection timed out occurs sometime.

JMeter's settings

```
- Thread
Number of Threads : 500
Ramp-Up Period : 50

- HTTP Request
Connect timeout : 20000ms
Response timeout : 40000ms

- Constant timer
Thread delay : 1000ms
```

CentOS7 settings

```
open files                      (-n) 65535
max user processes              (-u) 65535
```

Java execution settings

```
-Xmx8g -Xms4g -Xmn2g -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=16
```

Spring Boot application.properties Tomcat settings

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=20000
server.tomcat.max-connections=100000
server.tomcat.threads.max=10000
server.tomcat.threads.min-spare=2500
server.tomcat.accept-count=10000
```

JMeter works normally up to 10,000~20,000 requests, but connection timeout occurs after that.

```
Starting standalone test @ Fri Apr 16 09:30:29 KST 2021 (1618533029412)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +      1 in 00:00:03 =    0.4/s Avg:  1319 Min:  1319 Max:  1319 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 127 Started: 127 Finished: 0
summary +   8771 in 00:00:28 =  318.5/s Avg:   398 Min:   236 Max:  4191 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
summary =   8772 in 00:00:30 =  290.3/s Avg:   398 Min:   236 Max:  4191 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   9349 in 00:00:30 =  311.6/s Avg:   534 Min:   237 Max:  3582 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
summary =  18121 in 00:01:00 =  300.9/s Avg:   468 Min:   236 Max:  4191 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   5872 in 00:00:30 =  195.7/s Avg:  1494 Min:   235 Max: 20855 Err:    10 (0.17%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
summary =  23993 in 00:01:30 =  265.9/s Avg:   719 Min:   235 Max: 20855 Err:    10 (0.04%)
```

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to <IP Address>:<Port> [/112.220.184.107] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:336)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:843)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 19 more
```

[image: CPU]
[image: Request]
[image: Transaction]
[image: Thread]

Can you tell me why it happens?

Comment: check for open file descriptors, does JMeter create a new connection all the time (does not seem so), check gc pause

Answer (score 2):

```
summary +   5872 in 00:00:30 =  195.7/s Avg:  1494 Min:   235 Max: 20855 Err:    10 (0.17%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
```

Your response time increases above 20 seconds hence Tomcat rejects the connection (most probably the setting acts as the protection from [slow HTTP attacks](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-research/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks)

either set it to `-1` to disable it or use a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to see what is causing the problem on your application/tomcat end.

Also JMeter command-line output doesn't tell the full story, I would recommend generating some charts from the .jtl results file like [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime), [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime), [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond), etc. so you could correlate various performance metrics. It's also a good idea to monitor server-side operating system health metrics like CPU, RAM, Network, Swap, Disk usage as well as JVM JMX metrics, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: I've uploaded my JMeter PerfMon results, but I can't find why it happens..